# ListView not update after insert new Data

Tags: android, android-listview

This is my Main Activity where I call showData funtion and pass to
the adapter

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button add,add1;
    ListView list;
    Database db;
    ArrayList<studentmodel>data;
    EditText roll, name, fname, student_class;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new Database(this);
        add = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        list=findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        data=new ArrayList<>();
        data=db.showData();
        CustomAdapter ad=new CustomAdapter(this,data);
        list.setAdapter(ad);
        data=db.showData();
        ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is my Custom Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    ArrayList<studentmodel> student;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<studentmodel> student) {
        super(context, R.layout.customlayout, student);
        this.context = context;
        this.student = student;

    }

    public studentmodel getItem(int position) {
        return student.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View i, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customlayout, parent, false);
        studentmodel s1 = student.get(position);
       TextView adresult=view.findViewById(R.id.txtAddResult);
       TextView delete=view.findViewById(R.id.txtDeleteResult);
       TextView name=view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
       TextView s_class=view.findViewById(R.id.txts_class);
       TextView roll=view.findViewById(R.id.txtRoll);
       name.setText(s1.getStudent_name());
       s_class.setText(s1.getStudent_class());
       roll.setText(String.valueOf(s1.getStudent_roll()));
       adresult.setOnClickListener(v -> {
           Intent intent=new Intent(context,AddResult.class);
           context.startActivity(intent);
       });
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my dialog where I add student information

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        View view=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.customdialog,null);
        builder.setView(view);
        name=view.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        roll=view.findViewById(R.id.edtRoll);
        student_class=view.findViewById(R.id.EdtClassName);
        add1=view.findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        add1.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
            String sname=name.getText().toString();
            String sturoll=roll.getText().toString();
            String sclass=student_class.getText().toString();
            if(sname.equals("")||roll.equals("")||sclass.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                int sroll = Integer.parseInt(sturoll);
                studentmodel student = new studentmodel(sroll, sname, sclass);
                int i = db.studentInsertion(student);
                if (i == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data is inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data is not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });builder.show();
    }

}
```

When I open my application first time Data of a student is show but
when I insert new data in database with the help of dialog then this Data is not show in ListView but when I finish my application and reopen then I see information of a student show which I entered and old data. I want to see my Data when I enter without  not closing my app

Comment: Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after the insertion has been made

Comment: I use  notifyDataSetChanged() after the insertion has been made but it is not work

Answer (score 2):

> **Important note:** It is not the best practice, fetching database content
> from the Main thread synchronously. It may causes UI blocking issue. Use any background thread to perform this task. Like AsyncTask, Coroutines (If Kotlin)

At first on your **onCreate** method in Main Activity, remove unnecessary codes(Commented out).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new Database(this);
    add = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    list=findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    data = db.showData();
    CustomAdapter ad=new CustomAdapter(this, data);
    list.setAdapter(ad);
    // data=db.showData();
    // ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now you have to pass CustomAdapter instance "**ad**", inside your AlertDialog class. From there you can notify that data set changed by calling ***ad.notifyDataSetChanged()*** method.

```
//...
studentmodel student = new studentmodel(sroll, sname, sclass);
int i = db.studentInsertion(student);
ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
//...
```

Hopefully you can overcome your problem. If not let me know.

Comment: I have use your method but my problem is not solve we have to minimize then data update

Comment: @Mubashar Ali
 May I have the best explanation of "we have to minimize then data update". It's actually not clear to me.